# Haystack __contains not finding substrings passed through GET [ElasticSearch backeng]

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have the following model:

```
class ProductIndex(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    number = indexes.CharField()
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
```

In my webpage, I perform an AJAX call to a function that should return to me the products that have their description containing some words the used types. For example, if I have a product with a description "Apple Macbook Pro", and the user types "book", I want to return that result.

I perform the following:

```
q = request.GET['q']
results = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(description__contains=q)
```

However, like I said, I do have for example a product with the description:

`Macbook` and the user types `book`, it will not work. However, `Macbook` will work.

Finally, if I print `q`, it returns `u'book'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `indexes.EdgeNgramField` instead of `indexes.CharField`. This is suggested in the autocomplete documentation (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0.0/autocomplete.html).

You shouldn't need to change the querying code.

EDIT:

To make it case insensitive you could do something like this

```
class ProductIndex(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ... fields here ...
    def prepare_description(self, object):
        return object.description.lower()
```

and when querying use `lower()` on `q`

Comment: Good it works! However, it is case sensitive... anyways to get around this?

Comment: If you use `lower` in the `prepare_<field>` and the field is a faceted field, In the facets UI it will return lower case items which looks ugly :/

Comment: Ngram processing and  __contains are similar but not the same thing. This is not a correct answer.